# Linq is erroring for Range variable 'Username' hides a variable

Tags: linq, class, range, block

First the code:

```vb
Dim tCards = (From r In myDB.CAH_TableCards Join c In myDB.CAH_Cards On r.CardId Equals c.CardId Where r.GameId = oGame.GameId And r.Round = oGame.Round Select c).SingleOrDefault
Dim pCards = From r In myDB.CAH_PlayerCards Join c In myDB.CAH_Cards On r.CardID Equals c.CardId Where r.GameId = oGame.GameId And r.username = UserName Select c
Dim rcards As List(Of TableCard) = From z In myDB.CAH_RoundCards Join c In myDB.CAH_Cards On z.CardId Equals c.CardId Where z.GameId = oGame.GameId And z.Round = oGame.Round Select c.CardId, c.CardType, c.Text, c.Answers, c.SetId, c.Added, z.Username, z.Visible
```

Now the class:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Public Class TableCard
    Public CardId As Integer
    Public CardType As Integer
    Public Text As String
    Public Answers As Integer
    Public SetId As Integer
    Public Added As Date
    Public Visible As Boolean
    Public Username As String
End Class
```

Lastly this issue:

the official error is

> BC30978: Range variable 'Username' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.

Upon researching the error I have came up with zip, zilch, nada. now the error didn't occur until I added the `z.username` to the very end. prior to that it worked fine. the `Username` field is a valid field in that table. I have used `CAH_RoundCards` in other parts of the code with no issue. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out...earlier in the code, i had a varible called UserName...so i just changed that and it worked.

Comment: Further to this, if you're using linq in VB, variable names are case insensitive, so watch out for any variables that are the same but in a different case.